# checkboxes from code behind

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have 3 columns which are filled using binding in xaml from the database and then I have some columns which are dynamic in the `ListView`.  The columns which are dynamic have the headers filled from code behind such as :

```
viewLayout.Columns.Add(
    new GridViewColumn {       
        Header = subjectvalues_forstdatt[i],
        DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(String.Format("[{0}]", i))    
    }
);
```

I want a `CheckBox` in this dynamic column, not the content being showed by displaymemberbinding.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it but something like this should work:

```
  DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate { DataType = typeof(object) };  // <-- insert your concrete objet type here

  FrameworkElementFactory stackPanelFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
  stackPanelFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Vertical);

  FrameworkElementFactory checkbox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
  checkbox.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding(String.Format("[{0}]", subjectvalues_forstdatt[i]));
  stackPanelFactory.AppendChild(checkbox);


  viewLayout.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
  {

    Header = subjectvalues_forstdatt[i],
    CellTemplate = template
```

or I'd prefer writing the `DataTemplate` in XAML and access it via Key in CodeBehind..

```
CellTemplate = TryFindResource("myDataTemplateKey") as DataTemplate
```

Comment: I think the better way is to use SetResourceReference instead of TryFindResource ;)

Comment: thank you very much for your help i m really grateful. The second option worked well.But the other problem is how do i add the content into the checkbox like <CheckBox Content="{Binding subject_id}"> and according to an event get the subject id per row for the no of checkboxes clicked. Thank you very very much